# How to create In app browser in ibm worklight

Tags: javascript, worklight-studio

I have created php application for oauth authentication of gmail. I need to embed that php code to worklight application using in app browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.1.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html,
This is the latest version used by Worklight 6.1. take a look at it.

Answer (score 4):

You should look at utilizing Cordova's inappbrowser feature which can be used inside of Worklight applications:

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html

There is an article that was just published that shows how to use OAuth with inappbrowser using LinkedIn found at the following location. Please look at the section "OAuth and the InAppBrowser plug-in" for further detail as you can apply most of this information to your scenario:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/mo-worklight-linkedin/index.html